# Sqlite select column text with multple words

Tags: python, string, select, text, sqlite

So i have a table with all of the products and their language availability. I want to write a function to check the language availability when input the product name and language.

My code is as follow:

```
"CREATE TABLE t (Language,French, Italian, German, Spanish, Japanese, Korean, 'Traditional Chinese');")

   //insert data to table t 

 def checkLanguageAvailability(self, product, language):           
        query = "SELECT " + language + " FROM t WHERE Language = '" + product + "'"
        cur = self.df.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        # print cur.fetchall()
        res = cur.fetchall()
        if res[0][0] == '':
            return False
        elif int(float(res[0][0])) != 0:
            return True
```

so when i test it , it all works fine with one-word text

```
checkLanguageAvailability("productname",'French')) --> True
```

But with multiple-word text

```
checkLanguageAvailability("productname",'Traditional Chinese'))
```

it raise this error :

```
    cur.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Traditional
```

It seems that instead of taking the whole string 'Traditional Chinese' as a parameter, it just take 'traditional' and there is no column have this name in table

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your table structure and also with your code.  Adding a new column for each language is costly and maximally inflexible.  This approach requires a major schema change each time you decide to support a new language.  In addition, your current concatenated query string is prone to SQL injection.  Beyond this, you should generally not make the column names in a query as parameters.  When you find yourself doing this, it might indicate bad design or a hack.  Instead, I propose the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (language TEXT, product TEXT)
```

This design represents the presence of a given product and language as a single row.  Hence, if we find a record entry for a given product and language then we know it is present.

Try using code something like the following:

```
def checkLanguageAvailability(self, product, language):
    cur = self.df.cursor()
    cmd = cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE product = ? AND language = ?", (product, language))
    res = cur.fetchall()
    cnt = len(res)
    if cnt == 0
        return False
    else
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp):

```
def checkLanguageAvailability(self, product, language):           
        query = "SELECT " + language + " FROM t WHERE Language LIKE '%" + product + "%'"
        cur = self.df.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        # print cur.fetchall()
        res = cur.fetchall()
        if res[0][0] == '':
            return False
        elif int(float(res[0][0])) != 0:
            return True
```

And is this query accepting any external input? Because if so, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: You should be using prepared statements at least.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Very true, but I don't know Python to add an example.